# How to integrate woocommerce to flutter app

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I wanted to integrate flutter with woo-commerce, so whenever I upload products on my WordPress site, they should be automatically added to my app, app UI is almost complete, firebase is also attached with authentication! please help me and tell me what should I do in order to achieve it! also, I am a beginner!

Comment: Hi, Please them this URL and download the plugin and setup on your site, I think its more helpful for you https://github.com/woosignal/flutter-woocommerce-app#:~:text=Label%20StoreMax%20is%20an%20App,Google%20play%20store%20using%20Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here the documentation for REST API of woo-commerce which you need to integrate with in application in order to load products.
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

Comment: Thanks I will try it!